# Restore to remote database from my local machine

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, restore

I am registered at **Go Daddy** and want to restore the database there from my local machine. The tool they provide me with doesn't work unless it's from them. I'm trying to restore from my local SQL server, but when I browse I can't restore the local files of the remote database.

Answer (score 1):

They're intentionally preventing users from restoring backups that are "foreign" to them in order to satisfy an obscure Microsoft security recommendation.

You will have to perform a schema comparison and a data comparison between your local machine and the empty database on the hosting to generate the scripts to re-create all of the objects and data. (Having those scripts available in a source control storage would also be helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to restored the `Database` using `Sql Server`.

1. Through `SSMS` Restore Utility.
2. Manual Database restore Script from **[here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1217118-391-1.aspx#bm1217538)**